# Does there exist a strongly convex function that is strongly convex with respect to norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ for any $p > 2$?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

A function $f$ is said to be strongly convex with respect to a norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ if for all $x,y$, $$f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T(x-y) + \frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|^2_p.$$

There are a bunch of functions used in machine learning, statistics, etc. that are extremely well known to be strongly convex with respect to the $2$ or $1$ norm

Examples:

$\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j^2$ is 2-strongly convex with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$

$\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j \log(x_j) $ is 1-strongly convex with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$

Does there exist any strongly convex function with respect to a norm $\|\cdot\|_p, p>2$?

Comment: Does $0 \geq \dfrac{1}{2} (\max_i |x_i - y_i| )^2$ hold for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All norms are equivalent on $\mathbb R^m$, so a strongly convex function is strongly convex wrt any norm.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I'm perplexed. A lot of efforts are put in to prove things are strongly convex wrt a certain norm. Such as the Pinsker's inequality. https://mltheory.github.io/CS7545/scribe/lec3.pdf

Comment: Do you care about the constant before the norm term ? If so, my argument is useless.

Comment: @GabrielRomon If I don't care, then what you say is 100% true, and any strongly convex function in one norm is strongly convex in another with a slightly adjusted factor. If I do care, then I'm stuck

Comment: A lot of optimization algorithms will require you to know or be able to estimate the strong convexity constant to determine things like step size. You probably care.

Comment: It might be worth noting that sometimes the phrase "$\beta$-strongly convex" is used to refer to the inequality above with the $2$ norm fixed, and $\beta\|x-y\|_2^2/2$ instead of $\|x-y\|_p^2/2$. In those contexts, $\beta$ is called the strong convexity constant. Would you allow considering a function with a *different* constant for each $p$? i.e. a function $f$  such that, for every $p$, there exists $\beta_p$ such that the inequality above holds where $\beta_p\|x-y\|_p^2/2$ replaces $\|x-y\|_p^2/2$?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by that. In finite dimensional spaces, as other people noted, all norms are equivalent. However, the constants relating them can scale with the dimension.

If you are interested in functions that would have a strong convexity constant that is independent of the dimension (while having dimension independent divergence on sets of dimension-independent diameters), then no such function exists for $p > 2.$ For proof, see Example 4.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0465.pdf.